# Macbook Pro 2018 doesn't actually shut down

Tags: macbook-pro

I shut down my Macbook every day after i stop working, but while it looks shut down (screen off etc), it's actually not.

The battery is drained to 0% in the morning, and it stays hot / warm for up to 12 hours (until the battery is empty) I only noticed this, after i carried it in my backpack and i was surprised that it was really hot, as if i was using it at the moment. If you think "that's just the heat from your back", this also happens when the macbook is placed on a table for several hours, in a cool room. After i switch it off, it stays hot for several hours.

To further test that it's not the battery (or a hardware issue in general), i did the following: Since the battery drains over night, i left the macbook laying on a weekend to drain it to 0%. When it was cold and didn't turn on, i plugged it in and charged it for several hours so it's full. I switched it on the next day, and the battery was still fully charged. This leads me to believe that whatever which is disrupting the "being off", is only killed after the battery power is gone.

I am very sure that this is caused by a software or system component, which is running despite the system is "shut down", because a shut down macbook should not get hot.

This all started occuring since the 11.3 or 11.2 update.

I did PRAM and SMC resets to no avail. Wake on Bluetooth and stuff is off. And i know how crazy this sounds.

Comment: Schöner Name @meisterdieb ;)... When you "turn it off" and then open it again, what happens? Does it go through the normal startup sequence or is it just waking from sleep?

Comment: Danke :) It stays dark, i have to press the button to actually turn it on. Recently it doesn't immediately turn on either, it takes a few minutes on the charger to do that.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is to make a backup. There is *something* wrong with the system and unless you have no valuable data on the machine data loss is the worst possible outcome. If you have a USB drive you can use TimeMachine (or other backup tools) or simply copy the files. To rule out software issues you *could* try to reinstall macOS by wiping the drive first to ensure you start from scratch. If possible you could also try to install macOS on another external drive (preferably an SSD) and and boot from there. If problems persist in either scenario its a hardware fault.

Comment: We should first try to determine if the issue is on the Intel side or on the T2 side. What does `pmset -g log` tell you around the timestamp when you expect your machine to be turned off?

Comment: @X_841 reinstallation would be my last resort, i will do a backup.

@pion here are the messages. Shut down at 22:00. Boot at 8:22.

`2021-07-08 22:00:47 +0200 Assertions           PID 171(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context1659.preventuseridlesleep" 01:13:25  id:0x0x100008197 [System: DeclUser kDisp]`

`2021-07-09 08:22:52 +0200 ShutdownCause        SMC shutdown cause: 5: Software initiated shutdown`

`Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2021-07-07 15:54:30 +0200 :0   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:0`

Comment: @meisterdieb Please put the log in a separate file and upload it somewhere (e.g. pastebin.com) and edit your question to include the link to it.